# Instantons on the 4-sphere with respect to other Riemannian metrics

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, gt.geometric-topology, gauge-theory

It is known that the moduli space of $\text{SU}(2)$ instantons of charge $1$ on $S^4$ is diffeomorphic to the five-ball $B^5$ if $S^4$ is endowed with the round metric.

Question: what does the moduli space look like if we put different metrics on $S^4$? In particular, metrics that coincide with the round metric near $\infty$?